# Display a messagebox when systemtime matches time in txt file?

Tags: vbscript

I have written a script that creates a text file with an hour offset, when the system time matches the time in the file I want a messagebox to display a message

I've tried the following code but it doesn't work

```
LicTimeLoc = "J:\Groups\Design\Student Work\UStationTest\LicT.txt"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set LicTimeCheck = fso.CreateTextFile(LicTimeLoc, True)
LicTimeCheck.WriteLine DateAdd("s",5,Now())
LicTimeCheck.Close

Set LicTimeCheck = fso.OpenTextFile(LicTimeLoc)
NextLic = LicTimeCheck.ReadAll
Do Until Now = NextLic
Loop
msgbox "License now available"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the details of what I wanted [here](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/Script-to-compare-time-m1393.aspx)

I edited it to suit my needs and now when the system time is greater than the compared value it shows a message

```
LicTimeLoc = "J:\Groups\Design\Student Work\UStationTest\LicT.txt"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set LicTimeCheck = fso.CreateTextFile(LicTimeLoc, True)
LicTimeCheck.WriteLine DateAdd("s",5,Time())
LicTimeCheck.Close

Set LicTimeCheck = fso.OpenTextFile(LicTimeLoc)
NextLic = LicTimeCheck.ReadAll

comparetime = TimeValue(NextLic)

Do until comparetime < systime
systime = time
Wscript.Sleep(1000)
loop
msgbox "License now available"
```